# While Writing a .csv file in java tabs are not coming in excel

Tags: java

I want to write a .csv file using some data using JAVA. While I am able to get the CSV file but I am not getting them as TAB deliminator. I want to keep the file type as .csv but the values should be tab deliminated. My code is as follows,

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

StringBuffer fileNameFormat = new StringBuffer();
fileNameFormat.append( "attachment; filename= ReferenceData");
fileNameFormat.append(".csv");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition",fileNameFormat.toString());
StringBuffer totalString =new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer header=new StringBuffer();

header.append("ReferenceId");
header.append("\t");
header.append("TYPE");
header.append("\t");
header.append("VALUE");
header.append("\t");
header.append("ENABLED");

StringBuffer body=new StringBuffer();
if (null != responseBody && responseBody.getResultArray().length > 0) { 
DvrReferenceData[] obj=responseBody.getResultArray();
int responseLength = responseBody.getResultArray().length;
                for(int i=0;i<responseLength;i++){

                DvrReferenceData obj1=obj[i];

                body.append(obj1.getRefId());
                body.append("\t");
                body.append(obj1.getRefType());
                body.append("\t");
                body.append(obj1.getRefValue());
                body.append("\t");
                body.append(obj1.getEnabled());
            body.append("\n");
            }

        }

        totalString.append(header.toString());
```

totalString.append("\n");
            totalString.append(body.toString());
            out.write(totalString.toString());`

Excel is not reading the '\t' when I am giving the file format as .csv, but its happening if i give the file format as .xls `enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `sep=;` at the first line of CSV file that will instruct the Excel to split the cell based on semicolon.

Use `;` as separator instead of `\t` for each value when writing into CSV file.

**Don't** forget to enclose the value inside double quotes.

Here is the sample code:

```
sep=;
"ReferenceId";"TYPE";"VALUE";"ENABLED"
"1";"T1";"V1","true"
"2";"T2";"V2","true"
"3";"T3";"V3","false"
```

Comment: Actually I want to display the csv in Excel file, and the value should be separated by a tab meaning the value should come in different Cells. Please help me in that.

Comment: Also if I want to put a separator in the java code how should I write it

Comment: Its very simple `out.write("sep=;\n")` before adding anything in response stream. then write header in second line then add the actual data. Don't forget to enclose the header and data inside double quote.